Whose when or when whose - Are both the provided sentences grammatically sound?
Let's say there are multiple people, all of whom have soccer matches to play on a certain day. If you wanted to say you know whose game will end at what time, which of the following would you use:

I know whose game ends when.
I know when whose game ends.

Grammarly suggests the second one is grammatically dubious because of "whose game." I'm not a native speaker, and both sentences seem grammatically okay to me. Are they grammatically okay? Which would you use if you had to pick one of these sentences?

The first sentence is idiomatic. The second is not. It does not sound at all natural.  That same string of words could constitute a question though, as in response to the utterance, “You know when her game ends.” “I know when whose game ends?”

I couldn't give a grammatical reason why (1) sounds natural and (2) doesn't. It would be more idiomatic to say "I know when everyone's game ends".

"I know which game ends when" is an alternative. But certainly expressions such as "I know what happens when" are common.

I'd say that when cannot be complemented by an interrogative content clause except in "meta speech-act" replies of the sort Paul gives in a comment above, which take the form "I 'know when whose game ends' ", that is, where parts of the statement are repeated back and the word in the slot that corresponds to the word that needs explaining is emphasized.

Another possibility: "I know when each player's game ends."
